# Can someone please show step-wise how to integrate the following?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Supposedly, integration and simplification of $$a_n=\frac{2}{l} \int_0^a\frac{hx}{a}\sin \frac{n\pi x}{l}dx + \frac{2}{l}\int_a^l \frac{h(l-x)}{l-a} \sin \frac{n \pi x}{l} dx$$ is to yield $$a_n=\frac{2hl^2}{n^2\pi^2a(l-a)} \sin \frac{n\pi a}{l},$$ however, I've trying all day to prove this but I can't seem to be getting the same answer. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

it's not so difficult (sorry for bad english and gramathic, hope someone can help me editing ).

At fitst look the fitst integral, you can reduce it to a more accesifull integral, try solving $$\displaystyle\int x\sin(bx)dx$$
Then you have to multiply by $\frac{h}{a}$ and do $b=\frac{n\pi}{\ell}$
this is easy to calculate for integration by parts.

Then for the second integral try solving $\displaystyle\int(\ell-x)\sin(\frac{x}{\ell})dx$ (pst. multiply sin by l and rest sin*x, this is more easy for integrate), then return to original form by multiply for some factor , evaluate the integrals and the rest its yours.